# Bootstrap Modal AJAX Call Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show a modal dialog on a list of search results that are displayed in a table. When the user clicks the button to show the dialog I need to pass a value from the PHP code to the modal dialog so it can retrieve data about the record they have clicked on which will then appear in the modal dialog.

Here's the HTML for the table of results:

```
 <tr>
 <td><button class="btn btn-default" recid="33926"  onclick="showModal(33926)">Review</button></td><td>1</td><td>Pending</td><td>001</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><button class="btn btn-default" recid="33951"  onclick="showModal(33951)">Review</button></td><td>1</td><td>Pending</td><td>002</td>
 </tr>
```

Here's the Javascript that gets called when the Review button is clicked:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function showModal(recid)
        {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
           {
           if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
             {
             document.getElementById("myModal").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
             }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","modalInc.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("recid="+recid);
        return false;  // Do not follow hyperlink
        }
      </script>
```

and here's the html for the modal dialog that should appear with the dynamic content:

```
  <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Title</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="modalContent">

            </div>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Approve</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Reject</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">On Hold</button>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The modal dialog isn't being shown at the moment - I suspect there's the Javascript isn't calling it correctly but I can't seem to get the correct syntax for this.

Comment: Mate, you are only setting the innerHTML of the `myModal` element. You are not showing it actually!

Comment: @AntoanMilkov - thanks, I can't get the correct syntax to show the modal dialog. Do you know what this should be?

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are returning modal html already. You are setting modal dialog html but you need to trigger modal also. You can use following;

`...
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
     var modalObj = document.getElementById("myModal");
     modal.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
     modal.modal();
}
.....`

Comment: Thanks @Hüseyin BABAL - I've changed the code but the modal dialog is still not showing. I checked the server logs and the AJAX request is being called but for some reason the modal dialog is not appearing. Any ideas?

Comment: Any logs in browser console? Do you see that ajax response coming?